# Elasticsearch : nested VS flat indicies

Tags: elasticsearch

What are the pros and cons of a nested index in Elasticsearch ?

I am thinking about temporal data of some users or devices so by flat I mean all data are stored at the root of the index and nested I mean data is group by device / id. So there is one document by user/device id that contains one document per entry of time.

**I see as pros :**

- Nested indices offer more querying possibility

**And as cons :**

- Write is more costly
- Index management could be really more difficult (how to expire the data ? No easy index rolling, how to easily spread the data into different indices ?)

Answer (score 7):

Let's talk about pros and cons among `flat fields`, `dynamic`, `object`, `flattened`, `nested`.

### flat fields

pros: Simple and clear, field type is specified in mappings.

cons: New field should do `put mapping` at first. Number of fields is limited by engine. Different fields have no relationship.

### dynamic

For new fields or inner object which have no mappings represented.

set to false, will not index new fields, but new fields can be retrieved by `_source`.

set to strict, will report an error when unknown new fields in doc.

cons: strict is not elastic meanwhile dynamic will lead a mapping explosion problem, as Elasticsearch limit the max number of feild to 1000 by default, see also `index.mapping.total_fields.limit: 1000`

### flattened

Better type than daynamic, comes with 7.3 +

pros: unlimited number of fields, all things flattened as its name described.

cons: only support few query: term or exist, no highlight.

### object

Object is another default when you using `{}` in mappings.

pros: nature supported, also for inner object

cons: not support array of object. Elasticsearch actually has no concept of inner object.Therefore, it flattens object hierarchies into a simple list of field names and values, checkout https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects

### nested

pros: Support complex structure of array of objects or object of arrays and also keep them separately, therefore the field relation inside single object is kept. Suppose we have a candidate indices and lots of candidates have multiple education backgrounds. with nested fields, we can now retrieve candidates graduated from CMU with a major in CS.

cons: Each nested object is indexed as a separate Lucene document, 1 doc with 100 nested object will create 101 Lucene documents.

Both fields and objects inside nested have limits, default to 50 and 10000.

see also
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_limits_on_nested_mappings_and_objects

Answer (score 5):

Totally agree with you about pros and cons of ES nested type. Just want to elaborate the deepth of indexing cost. **Keep in mind nested field opens query facilities also**

If you use nested type and **infrequent** modification then it is awesome and creates broader scope for query but if you do **frequent** change then it will do huge cost.

`nested` type mapping has more impact in terms of indexing over flat type mappings. Since **Lucene does not have any concept of nested object types, and everything is stored as flat objects**. So there is an additional operation performed at the indexing time.

Imagine you have a large nested document that translates to 100k internal documents and compare this to a flat data model where we have indexed the 100k parts as independent documents. If we add a single nested document at the deepest, nested level, this would add a single flat document while the nested document would end up reindexing 100k+ 1 documents. If you on the other hand change something at the root, all documents need to be updated in both cases. So you can imagine a single doc change can cost you reindexing all nested field of that document.